# Express JS vs pure Node.js - performance benchmarks?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a question - does anyone has any benchmark data re. using Express JS framework vs pure Node.js?

Is this something that even should be considered -- or using Express or similar framework is definitely a MUST if you're building a more or less large web app?

Comment: Yes, it is a must, there is no need to reinvent the wheel. And probably, their wheel will be better than yours because it's their duty to optimize routing and other bunch of stuff in Express

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Express is a convenience wrapper around node.js, and should not add much latency to your server; your code would probably go through many of the same steps anyway. That being said, if your load tests (or hapless customers) find the server is too slow and/or not scalable, then you should profile at that time, and the bottleneck probably won't be Express.

BTW, even though Express [calls itself "high performance"](http://expressjs.com/), they're [naughty](http://xkcd.com/285/) for not posting measurements.

Answer (score 29):

> **EDIT:**
>
> The article I linked to below disappeared, and I couldn't find it after searching around a bit.  However, in lieu of that, here are a couple of relevant references with sufficiently scientific benchmarks:
>
> - https://github.com/koajs/koa/blob/master/docs/koa-vs-express.md#is-koa-faster-than-express
> - http://serdardogruyol.com/?p=111
> - http://qzaidi.github.io/2013/07/20/surprises/

Although this doesn't answer the delta part of your question, there's some absolute statistics about ExpressJS performance here:

[Updated Link](http://web.archive.org/web/20121027010501/http://blog.perfectapi.com/2012/benchmarking-apis-using-perfectapi-vs-express.js-vs-restify.js/)

http://blog.perfectapi.com/2012/benchmarking-apis-using-perfectapi-vs-express.js-vs-restify.js/

Looks like, on a small Amazon instance, Express averages:

> a very respectable 1,600-1,700 requests per second